# How to combine two Wikipedia API calls into one?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm making a call to a Wikipedia API which returns a Title, Shot-Text, Image and geo-cordinates of that location. My Wikipedia API is:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts|pageimages|coordinates&titles=Berlin&redirects=1&formatversion=2&exintro=1&explaintext=1&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=400
```

Also I'm using another Wikipedia API which returns a list of place names according to their geo-coordinates:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=1000&gscoord=52.5243700|13.4105300&gslimit=50&gsprop=type|dim|globe
```

For the second API I get a response like this:

```
"query": {
    "geosearch": [
        {
            "pageid": 28782169,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "1757 Berlin raid",
            "lat": 52.523405,
            "lon": 13.4114,
            "dist": 122.4,
            "primary": "",
            "type": null,
            "dim": 1000
        },
        {
            "pageid": 526195,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Scheunenviertel",
            "lat": 52.526111111111,
            "lon": 13.41,
            "dist": 196.9,
            "primary": "",
            "type": "landmark",
            "dim": 1000
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now I want to combine these two searches in one API. I want to add information from my first API within the second API, something like as below:

```
"query": {
    "geosearch": [
        {
            "pageid": 28782169,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "1757 Berlin raid",
            "lat": 52.523405,
            "lon": 13.4114,
            "dist": 122.4,
            "primary": "",
            "type": null,
            "dim": 1000

            "pages": [
                {
                    "pageid": 28782169,
                    "ns": 0,
                    "title": "1757 Berlin raid",
                    "extract": "Berlin is the capital of Germany and one of the 16 states of Germany. With a population of 3.5 million people, it is the second most populous city proper and the seventh.........",
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Siegessaeule_Aussicht_10-13_img4_Tiergarten.jpg/400px-Siegessaeule_Aussicht_10-13_img4_Tiergarten.jpg",
                        "width": 400,
                        "height": 267
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to know is it possible in this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, if I understand right, you want with one Wikipedia API request to get a **title**, **shot-text**, **image** and **geo-cordinates** (your first API) for all the places (Wikipedia articles) that are located in a certain area by given coordinates and radius (your second API). If that correct, you can do it in this way:

1. [main parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=main): `format=json&action=query`
2. [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query):

   - `redirects=1`
   - `generator=geosearch` (your second API: see point 3)
   - `prop=extracts|coordinates|pageimages` (your first API: see point 4, 5, and 6)
3. [geosearch parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bgeosearch) (all generator parameters are prefixed with a *"g"*):

   - `ggslimit=20` - your total results from the query (because the `exlimit=20`)
   - `ggsradius=1000&ggscoord=52.5243700|13.4105300` - this is your entry point
4. [parameters for extracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts): `exintro=1&explaintext=1&exlimit=20` (max `exlimit` is 20)
5. [parameters for coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcoordinates): `coprop=type|dim|globe&colimit=20` (max `colimit` is 500)
6. [parameters for pageimages](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageimages): `piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=400&pilimit=20` (max is 50)

How you see, the max `colimit` is 500 and the max `pilimit` is 50, but we can't use more than 20, because of `exlimit`.

Or finally, your request will be the joining of all parameters above:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&redirects=1&generator=geosearch&prop=extracts|coordinates|pageimages&ggslimit=20&ggsradius=1000&ggscoord=52.5243700|13.4105300&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exlimit=20&coprop=type|dim|globe&colimit=20&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=400&pilimit=20
```

And here is the response:

```json
"query":{
    "pages":{
        "2511":{
            "pageid":2511,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Alexanderplatz",
            "extract":"Alexanderplatz (pronounced [\u0294al\u025bk\u02c8sand\u0250\u02ccplats]) is a large public square and transport hub in the central Mitte district of Berlin, near the Fernsehturm. Berliners often call it simply Alex, referring to a larger neighbourhood stretching from Mollstra\u00dfe in the northeast to Spandauer Stra\u00dfe and the Rotes Rathaus in the southwest.",
            "coordinates":[
                {
                    "lat":52.52166748,
                    "lon":13.41333294,
                    "primary":"",
                    "type":"landmark",
                    "dim":"1000",
                    "globe":"earth"
                }
            ],
            "thumbnail":{
                "source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Alexanderplatz_by_the_night_-_ProtoplasmaKid.webm/400px--Alexanderplatz_by_the_night_-_ProtoplasmaKid.webm.jpg",
                "width":400,
                "height":225
            }
        },
        ...
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Termininja and how can I request the next results page?

Comment: @Termininja I meant how to get the next 20 nearest places. Your request's response does not have a <code>continue</code> parameter

Comment: @allo86 I already answered this - you can't have [more than 20 results](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts)